# How to build a JSONObject with a JSONArray?

Tags: java, json, format

im kinda new using JSON, and everything was fine until i have to make this JSON format.

"function":"ListarHoteles",
"parameters":[""]

Right now my code:

```
        JSONObject JSONarr = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray pam = new JSONArray();
        jo.put("function", "ListarHoteles");
        pam.add(" ");

        JSONObject mainOBJ = new JSONObject();
        mainOBJ.put("parameters", pam);
```

And im receiving: 
{"{\"function\":\"ListarHoteles\"}":{},"parameters":[" "]}
Thank you

Comment: I don't quite get what output you want. You want your JSONObject to be like this, right? {"function":"ListarHoteles", "parameters":[""]}

Comment: Please add more information about your problem. I can't understand.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("function", "ListarHoteles");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.add("");
jsonObject.put("parameters", arr);

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(2));
```

Output:

```
{
    "function":"ListarHoteles",
    "parameters":[
      ""
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate,  I'm new in JSON projects and this was exactly what I was looking for, I'm reading documentation right now.